# Estimation of Parametric survival model in R

Tags: survival, regression-coefficients, nonparametric

I fit an exponential survival model using flexsurv package.

```
fs1 <- flexsurvreg(Surv(recyrs, censrec) ~ group, data = bc,dist = "exp")
Estimates: 
             data mean  est      L95%     U95%     se       exp(est)  L95%   
rate              NA    0.06038  0.04589  0.07945  0.00846       NA        NA
groupMedium  0.33382    0.81802  0.48244  1.15361  0.17122  2.26601   1.62001
groupPoor    0.33236    1.53752  1.21844  1.85661  0.16280  4.65305   3.38190
             U95%   
rate              NA
groupMedium  3.16961
groupPoor    6.40199
```

The output includes an estimate of the rate parameter, which I thought is a function of covariates rather than a constant. Is this an estimate of intercept?

Thanks,
Peter